# Проверка порта на открытость

Tags: java, сокет

Добрый день. Я хотел бы с помощью java проверить, открыт ли необходимый мне порт по заданному айпи. Я пишу вот так

```
Socket s =new Socket("айпи",порт, который требуется проверить);
```

Если порт закрыт, то пишет

> ConnectException: failed to connect to (айпи)

а если открыт, но превышено время ожидания, то пишет:

> SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to (айпи)

Я правильно понимаю название и причину ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем. `ConnectException`может быть кинуто и в случае, IP неверный. А `SocketTimeoutException` может быть кинуто и в случае, если дорогу преградил firewal, и когда есть проблемы раутинга

Короче, вопрос в том, насколько точный диагноз требуется, т.е. насколько точно надо разделять

- неправлиный адресс
- неправлиный порт
- проблемы раутинга
- firewall

Короче, для первого приближения можно действительно попробовать подключиться и, если кинут exception, диагностировать закрытый порт. Но для более точной диагностики надо попробовать ping (`InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).isReachable()`). Если, например, ping работает, но к конкретному порту не подключиться - скорее всего порт закрыт.